# Sorting records by a child method and grouping by another association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord

Alright, so here's the example setup:

`House` has many `CompletedJobs` which belong to a single `Person`

`CompletedJobs` has a method called `total_score` which is dynamically generated based on data in the model. The output is an integer greater than zero. For example:

```
@completed_job1.total_score    #>output: 25
@completed_job2.total_score    #>output: 13
```

What I'm wanting to do is grab the top 20 `CompletedJobs` based on their aggregated score from the last 2 `Houses`, and also return the name of the `Person` that did them.

Example pseudocode would look like this:

```
House
  .last(2)
  .sort_by{ SUM_OF_COMPLETED_JOBS_GROUPED_BY_PERSON }
  .map{ [SUM_OF_PERSONS_JOB_SCORE, PERSON] }
  .first(20)
```

I've tried several approaches (both starting from `House` and starting from `Person` in the query), but I'm really perplexed on how to group the sum of the scores by the person, and then map them into an array.

Another example of how it could be done in SQL (pseudocode):

```
SELECT SUM(&:total_score), person_name
  FROM completed_jobs
    JOINS people ON completed_job.person_id = people.id
  WHERE completed_jobs.created_at > 1.week.ago ## < There are 2 per week,
                                               ##   so this would grab the 2 most recent
  GROUP_BY completed_job.person_id
  ORDER BY &:total_score DESC
  LIMIT 20
```

I can provide more information if necessary.

How can I assemble this query in Rails?

**Update**

The following query works well for grabbing each list of `CompletedJobs` per `House`

```
# For example, let's say we only have two houses
h1 = House.first
h2 = House.last

h1_a = h1.completed_jobs.sort_by(&:total_score).map{|cj| [cj.total_score, cj.person.name]}

h2_a = h2.completed_jobs.sort_by(&:total_score).map{|cj| [cj.total_score, cj.person.name]}
```

How can I combine `h1` and `h2` and then sort by the highest total score?

**Update 2**

I was able to combine and sum the values like so:

```
(h1_a + h2_a).group_by(&:last).map{|k,v| [k, v.map(&:first).inject(:+)]}
```

How can all of this be done in a single query? What I've done certainly works, but it seems too hacky :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure what do you want to get - a single SQL query? or short Ruby one-liner?

Ruby code:

```
# load all data into memory
houses = House.all.includes(completed_jobs: :person).last(2)

# process all in memory
houses.flat_map(&:completed_jobs).sort_by(&:total_score).last(20).group_by(&:person)
```

SQL query (I see that the only way is to make a sub-query):

```
SELECT t.name, SUM(t.total_scope)
FROM (
  SELECT p.name, j.total_score
  FROM houses h           // may be this table is excessive but...
    JOIN completed_jobs j ON j.house_id = h.id
    JOIN persons p ON p.id = j.person_id
  WHERE j.created_at > :week_ago_parameter
  ORDER BY j.total_score
  LIMIT 20
) t
GROUP BY t.name
```